# To find the transpose of a given matrix

Tags: python

I have been trying to run the code but its giving error that - "list index out of range"

What is the reason?
And is there any other way to find the transpose of a matrix without using numpy

This is the code I wrote

```
n = int(input("Enter the size of square matrix"))
matrix = []
for i in range(n):  
   a =[]
   for j in range(n):  
       a.append(int(input("Enter the entries rowwise:")))
   matrix.append(a)
matrix1 = []
for i in range(0,n):
   b = []
   for j in range(0,n):
        matrix1[i][j] = matrix[j][i]

for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
        print(matrix1[i][j], end = " ")
print()
```

What is the reason for the error in the line `matrix1[i][j] = matrix[j][i]`?
And is there any other way to find the transpose of a matrix without using numpy

Comment: your indentation is not correct  print(matrix1[i][j], end = " ")

Comment: And i suggest to use 4 space indent instead of 3 spaces indent

Comment: @YashMehta Actually that happened while copying the code from IDE

Comment: @iotainhills oh that's fine please update your code formatting.. also check my answer as you are also looking for other way to find the transpose of a matrix. Hope you will like it.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matrix1` is a list of dim 1 you try to index it as it already is a 2-d list. Try to use the b list to append the elements of the transposed matrix and then append it to `matrix1` like below:

```
n = int(input("Enter the size of square matrix"))
matrix = []
for i in range(n):  
   a =[]
   for j in range(n):  
       a.append(int(input("Enter the entries rowwise:")))
   matrix.append(a)
matrix1 = []
for i in range(0,n):
   b = []
   for j in range(0,n):
        b.append( matrix[j][i])
   matrix1.append(b)
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
       print(matrix1[i][j], end = " ")
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **zip function** also for transpose.

**Example**

**Code:-**

```
matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
#print(matrix)
res=[]
for i in zip(*matrix):
    res.append(i)
print(res)
```

**Output:-**

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the matrix is "matrix" just go with:

```
transposed = list(zip(*matrix))
```